# AuthenticationToken is null

Tags: c#, live, single-sign-on, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm currently writing a C# metro app for the Windows 8 consumer preview which fetches some data from my REST-based web services. I want the app to authenticate against the services using the Windows Live account of the current user. Therefore, I added the Windows Live SDK to my solution and pasted the following snippet from the documentation into my login view:

```
LiveAuthClient liveClient = new LiveAuthClient();                
LiveLoginResult loginResult = await liveClient.Login(new string[] { "wl.signin" });
```

After the login call has succeeded, I want to pass the encrypted `AuthenticationToken` of the `LiveConnectSession` via SSL to my webservice which should decrypt the token and read the information it is interested in (that's what the documentation suggests for such a SSO scenario). But sadly, the `AuthenticationToken` property of the session is always `null`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you get this sorted out? If so, you could write up an answer yourself.

Comment: @Joachim I didn't find a solution for this problem. Currently, I'm using a simple username/password approach over HTTPS and will add delegated authentication later on.

Comment: Did the answer you checked work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and realised I had two issues with my configuration:

1. I didn't have a "Redirect domain" defined in the API settings of https://manage.dev.live.com
2. I wasn't using the overloaded LiveAuthClient constructor

For example in the API settings you specify:

> Redirect domain: `http://localhost/myapp`

You then use the constructor overload of the LiveAuthClient:

```
var authClient = new LiveAuthClient("http://localhost/myapp");
var loginResult = await authClient.LoginAsync("wl-signin");

//this should no longer be null
var authToken = loginResult.Session.AuthenticationToken;
```

The redirect URI doesn't need to point to a working endpoint from what I can tell, as long as the two values match you should be in business.

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered your app on the Live Connect app management site for Metro style apps? You need to register it [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=227628) for it to work with Live Services. It will give you following instructions after you have given the app package a name and publisher.