# How can I use the Live SDK on the client to login to my own Web API?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, live-sdk

Fellow programmers,

It is hard for me to wrap my head around this whole token based OAuth authorization flow so please forgive me my eventual stupidity and broken english (I'm from Poland).

I'm developing a web service using .NET's Web API 2 technology and 2 native clients: Windows Store (8.1) & Windows Phone 8.1.
Some controllers on the API side of course need authorization. I want the users not to be forced to create a new account in my system with seperate login data so I've decided to use Microsoft authentication.

I've created an application on [Live.com developers](https://account.live.com/developers/applications) and got my client ID & secret. Then I've enabled the Microsoft authentication in App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs with correct ID & secret.
Now, I've made a native client (Win Store app) using Live SDK 5.6 (newest available) and associated it with the store. I managed to sign in to my account in the client using that SDK and get some basic data about me just for testing purposes.

But that's all I managed to do. My question is:

How can I use the Live SDK on the client to login to my own Web API? What's the flow?

I've found this:
http://leastprivilege.com/2013/02/02/asp-net-web-api-authentication-using-the-microsoft-account/
And it says I have to send the authentication token to my service using auth header, but my authentication token in null, I only have the access token. Also, to which URL do I send it?

Some other "useful" info about what I've done (will update):

- When creating the LiveAuthClient I didn't give the constructor any redirect URL

Comment: Please check the first answer in the below link .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572779/authenticationtoken-is-null